# Kivy get file path from two different files

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Im trying to get and store (for later use) 2 different file path from 2 different files (using drag and drop file).

I want to make 2 labeles and a button:

```
              "Drop Here Report(label)"  "Drop Here Source(label)"


                                 "Run(button)"
```

I need to define that only were the label is the user can drop the file and I just can't figure it up...

Here is my code so far:

```
class WindowFileDropExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.DropFile)
        return

    def DropFile(self, window, file_path):
        print(file_path)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WindowFileDropExampleApp().run()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Kivy's repo there's an [example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/miscellaneous/multiple_dropfile.py) of how to do multiple widgets for dropping down files with a lot of comments of how to do it.

Basically you'll need to make a "master" function that's bound to `on_dropfile` event. This function will work with a list of methods pulled out of a custom widgets. The list needs to be accessible through the widgets, so the `App` class seems like a reasonable choice. You can get it via `get_running_app()`

Such a widget will have a separate method you'd by default use for a single `on_dropfile` event and when the `on_dropfile` event is triggered, it'll launch each of those functions from list and *check* if the drop was in the area of the particular custom widget. If yes, it puts the path into `text` property. If not, another function gets the turn until the end of the list.